# Javascript placement in GWT HTML

Tags: java, gwt

What is the difference of placing a Javascript (.js) library on before the GWT application `nocache.js` and after `nocache.js` in a GWT application which uses the JS library in JSNI methods.

Does it affect wether a JSNI method will be functional or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal `<script>` tag are blocking, but the GWT script tag is not, since it is fetched asynchronously (i.e., non-blocking). The `onModuleLoad()` is called only when the body has been parsed (i.e., scripts have been fetched). Hence:

- put it as the very first script in your list: you will save time;
- `<script>` tags will always be loaded when `onModuleLoad()` is called.

Have a look at [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideBootstrap).

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on when the JSNI method is loaded.

To be safe - always check to see if the JS lib you are using has been loaded.  eg

```
public native static boolean isJqueryMethodLoaded(String method) /*-{
  if ($wnd.jQuery && $wnd.jQuery[method]) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}-*/;
```

(edited - thanks to the other answers for clarifying the load sequence)

Answer (score 1):

`onModuleLoad` is always called at or after `DOMContentLoaded`, and this will always happen after your scripts have loaded (because they could do `document.write()`), unless you loaded them with `async` or `defer`.

So, unless you load your "other JS" with `async` or `defer`, it really shouldn't matter in which order you load them, as `onModuleLoad` should always be called *after* both are loaded.